# Win 8 ,cygwin heap failure

Tags: windows, compilation, cygwin

I get the following error compiling with make (I have cygwin.dll)

```
   *** Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap (0x150000) in child, cygheap, Win32 error 0
          0 [main] make 4336 sync_with_child: child 2968(0x120) died before initialization with status code 0x1
        308 [main] make 4336 sync_with_child: *** child state waiting for longjmp
```

How could it be solved?
Thanks

Comment: Compiling which program? Hello World?

Comment: no.why is it important?i have a makefile for it .and it works ok on win7.

Comment: If it wasn't important I wouldn't be asking it. I'm trying to determine if this is a random problem, or if it's something that happens consistently, and if its something that is reproducible with the smallest possible application. Are you telling me that compiling a Hello World application doesn't trigger this error? Have you tested this?

Comment: it doesn`t work for any app.also restart doesn`t help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Reboot your system:

Most users complaining about this problem reported it goes away after a reboot. If you are using Windows 7, check the message from *BerndP* in [this thread](http://www.microchip.com/forums/m523322.aspx), it has some tips related to adjusting Virtual Memory settings on Windows.

- Might be some software interfering with Cygwin:

[This post](http://old.nabble.com/Couldn%27t-reserve-space-for-cygwin%27s-heap-win32-error-6-MSYS-Version-1.0.11-td29003310.html) brings an interesting discussion of random problems with Cygwin. The [BLODA list](http://cygwin.com/faq/faq.using.html#faq.using.bloda) presents a list of applications that are known to cause strange failures and problems in Cygwin.

**EDIT**:

Windows 8 has not been officially released, so [don't expect Cygwin to work on it](http://cygwin.com/faq/faq-nochunks.html#faq.what.supported).

> Cygwin can be expected to run on all modern 32 bit versions of Windows This includes, as of the time of writing this, Windows 2000, Windows XP, Windows Server 2003, Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008, Windows 7, as well as the WOW64 32 bit environment on released 64 bit versions of Windows (XP/2003/Vista/2008/7/2008 R2).

Comment: Yes, rebooting solved this problem on my Windows 8 machine.  I have 16Gb of RAM installed, and perhaps it was out of sync with my Virtual Memory settings...

Comment: Rebooting didn't help me even once on a Windows 8.1 64-bit machine with 32GB of RAM. The rebase fix worked though.

Answer (score 12):

I just ran into this problem and was advised to rebase the msys-1.0.dll which was causing the problem.

Specifically, I used the ReBase.exe tool:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\x64\ReBase.Exe
```

which is part of v7.1 (and perhaps other versions) of Microsoft's platform sdk [available here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279).

take a backup of the dll, and then try this command line inside the platform sdk command prompt:

```
rebase -b 0x30000000 /path/to/msys-1.0.dll
```

this solved the issue for me.

for interest, my recommended virtual memory settings were set at around 3GB, and the actual allocated virtual memory was at 6GB.

Comment: I had this problem for quite a while before I finally decided to try the rebase fix. It worked like a charm although I don't fully understand the significance of the rebase address; I entered another one on Windows 8.1 64-bit. I used git's own rebase because I don't have Cygwin or similar installed. Just for reference, here is where I read about the fix: http://jakob.engbloms.se/archives/1403.

Answer (score 1):

I am working with eclipse and am using MinGW + Yagarto on Windows 8. Restarting did nothing.

I solved the issue by expanding my virtual memory, which was originally set to 896Mb and is not at 3000Mb and working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be resolved by changing the compatibility mode of gcc.exe (or whatever called by make) into Windows Xp (in Properties->compatibility)
However, the script must be executed as administrator to avoid multiple confirmations when calling gcc.exe